# RakNet 63 session limit

Tags: c++, windows, networking, raknet

I'm using raknet for tcp networking on windows server 2008, it can accept a lot of connections but can't receive packets from all of them: only 63 client's packets can be read.

Here is my receive code:

```
if (tcpInterface->ReceiveHasPackets())
    {

        for (packet = tcpInterface->Receive(); packet; tcpInterface->DeallocatePacket(packet), packet = tcpInterface->Receive())

        {
            TRACE("tcpInterface->GetConnectionCount(); %d \n", tcpInterface->GetConnectionCount());
            //sNetMgr->ReceivedPacket(packet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wonder if this is related:  "The maximum number of sockets that a Windows Sockets application can use is not affected by the manifest constant FD_SETSIZE. This value defined in the Winsock2.h header file is used in constructing the FD_SET structures used with select function. The default value in Winsock2.h is 64."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739169(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: i searched it but its not fixed my problem